# What is difference between __tablename__ and Table at FastApi

Tags: fastapi

I am new at FastApi i can not understand how migrations work in fast api

i want to now what difference between this two method for create Table in fastapi

```
type here
operation = Table(
    "operation",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("quantity", String),
    Column("figi", String),
    Column("instrument_type", String, nullable=True),
    Column("date", TIMESTAMP),
    Column("type", String),
)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("userss.id"))

    owner = relationship("Userr", back_populates="items")
```

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html ? Either style should work fine with alembic (there's no migrations built-in to SQLAlchemy, but Alembic is the migration tool from the same author / organization as sqlalchemy: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: FastAPI doesn't do migrations, or ORM. Are you asking about SQLAlchemy and Alembic?